# dkim=fail (no key for signature) receiving on Hotmail

Tags: smtp, outlook, virtualmin

I run my own mail server that has been running fine, but recently emails are getting caught up on SPAM and the only thing I can find is `dkim=fail (no key for signature)`. The mail server is based on a Virtualmin platform installed.

But when I send a test to mail-tester.com I get a 10/10 success and it reports DKIM is OK.

I have checked the IP address in blacklists and there's nothing there, I only use the mail server for my own applications so I know it's not used maliciously.

Not sure where to look other than to contact Microsoft about it?

Any ideas other than to contact Microsoft?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to the following link for troubleshooting your issue with Hotmail:
https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/pm/troubleshooting.aspx